# Configure Phalcon Flash output to use specific session adapter

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm using the Phalcon flash service to store temporary messages between HTTP redirects.

It worked great until I recently changed to a database session adapter. Now flash messages are being stored in the database but are not being deleted.

I don't want these messages to touch the database so I setup the previous session method in the DI but under a new *tempSession* entry.

```
public function initTempSession($options = [])
{
    $this->di->set(
        'tempsession',
        function () {
            $tempSession = new PhSession();
            $tempSession->start();
            return $tempSession;
        },
        true
    );
}
```

How can I configure the flash service to use this session function, rather than the 'default' database adapter?